# Uncaught TypeError: this.jq.fileupload is not a function in prime faces 4.0 when use mode="advance" ajax file uploader

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I used jsf 2.2.x version and primefaces 4.0. i also used jquery versions such as 1.10.1 and 2.1.4

```
<h:form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{bean.handleFileUpload}"
                      mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
                      update="messages"
                      sizeLimit="10000000"
                      fileLimit="3"
                      allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />

        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
</h:form>
```

as well as i use the headers as below.

```
<h:head>
    <title><h:outputText value="#{userBean.title}"/> - Dashboard</title>
    <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="xyz"/>
    <meta http-equiv="description" content="Dashboard"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</h:head>
```

There are no any other link or script tags between head tag. only style tags.

> web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>commons</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
        <param-value>51200</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
        <param-value>/tmp/</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

> Bean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {
    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        System.out.println("invoked");
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", 
        event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }
}
```

above code is extracted part from whole code.
please help me to solve this problem.thank you!

Comment: Does it work if you also add a `p:inputText` to the page? Or are there other previous errors?

Comment: yes. i also use `p:inputText` .it also call the bean methods successfully.but when i use `p:fileUpload` , it never called the backing bean methods and file not uploaded any where. there are no errors in the log file

Comment: @Kukeltje do you have any idea about this issue?If you have any idea ,can you help me please?

Comment: Do you manually include a jquery js file anywhere? And please try making a [mcve] and try (just try) with the [mcve] if it works on a newer PF version.

Comment: Thank you guy...You are awesome and thank you again for that idea.Now it works perfectly!