# Primefaces Wizard and fileUpload Uncaught TypeError: this.jq.fileupload is not a function

Tags: primefaces

I tried to create a new Wizard with <p:tab>, it seems to be working fine but when I try to implement it in here to replace with the richfaces fileUpload, it keep showing error in the console like this:
[image]

I have tried it in 1st to 3rd tabs, the fileUpload seems to be working fine, but when comes to 4th to 6th tabs, it keeps showing "Uncaught TypeError: this.jq.fileupload is not a function" in console and upload is not working either in frontend or backend.

I also added enctype="multipart/form-data" in <h:form> but it doesn't have any differences

Im currently working on Primefaces 8.0.5

It does not have any error in my log, only console.

```
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:panelGroup id="FLEXIBLE_TOPOLOGY">
            <sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                <h:form id="projectCreateWizardFrm">
                    <p:wizard flowListener="#{projectCreatePage.onFlowProcess}" id="projectCreateWizard"
                              widgetVar="projectCreateWizardWV"
                              showNavBar="#{projectCreatePage.webActionPending}" showStepStatus="true"
                              styleClass="wizard">

                        <p:tab id="project" titleStyleClass="notClickable">
                            <f:facet name="title">
                                ...
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:panel id="wizardProjectPnl">
                                <p:focus context="wizardProjectPnl" />
                                <div class="title2">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{msg['system_step']} 1 - #{msg['flexitopology_wizard_project_header']}" />
                                </div>
                                <p:spacer height="10" />
                                <h:panelGrid id="projectCreateStartTbl" columns="2" columnClasses="form-label, form-value">
                                    <h:panelGroup>
                                        ...
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:inputText id="projectName" value="#{projectCreatePage.project.name}" size="60" maxlength="100" autocomplete="false"
                                                 disabled="#{!projectCreatePage.webActionPending or (!projectCreatePage.showEdit and projectCreatePage.showDeploy)}" />

                                    <sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                                        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!projectCreatePage.qcsFlag}">
                                            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['workspace_create_project_hostingcustomer']}" />
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!projectCreatePage.qcsFlag}">
                                            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="customerEnabledChkBox" value="#{projectCreatePage.customerEnabled}"
                                                                     disabled="#{projectCreatePage.disabledAfterSaved}">
                                                <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{projectCreatePage.onCustomerEnabledChange}"
                                                        render="organizationLblPnl, organizationValPnl, environmentLblPnl, environmentValPnl, standaloneQasLblPnl, standaloneQasValPnl" />
                                            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                    </sec:authorize>

                                    <h:panelGroup id="organizationLblPnl">
                                        ...
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:panelGroup id="organizationValPnl">
                                        ...
                                    </h:panelGroup>

                                    <h:panelGroup id="environmentLblPnl">
                                        ...
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:panelGroup id="environmentValPnl">
                                        ...
                                    </h:panelGroup>

                                    <h:panelGroup id="organizationEnvironmentLblPnl">
                                        ...
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:panelGroup id="organizationEnvironmentValPnl">
                                        ...
                                    </h:panelGroup>

                                    <h:panelGroup>
                                        ...
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:panelGroup>
                                        ...
                                    </h:panelGroup>

                                </h:panelGrid>
                                <p:spacer height="10" />
                            </p:panel>
                        </p:tab>

                        <p:tab id="license" titleStyleClass="notClickable">
                            <f:facet name="title">
                                ...
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:panel id="wizardLicensePnl">
                                <div class="title2">
                                    ...
                                </div>
                                <p:spacer height="10" />
                                <h:panelGrid id="projectCreateLicenseTbl" columns="2" columnClasses="form-label, form-value">


                                    <h:panelGroup id="contractSlaLblPnl">
                                        ...
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:panelGroup id="contractSlaValPnl">
                                        ...
                                    </h:panelGroup>

                                    <h:panelGroup id="standaloneQasLblPnl">
                                        ...
                                    </h:panelGroup>

                                    <h:panelGroup id="licenseLblPnl">
                                        ...
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:panelGroup id="licenseValPnl" style="border:none;padding:0;">
                                        ...
                                    </h:panelGroup>

                                    <h:panelGroup id="licenseLblPnl2">
                                        ...
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:panelGroup id="licenseValPnl2" style="border:none;padding:0;">
                                        ...
                                    </h:panelGroup>

                                </h:panelGrid>
                                <p:spacer height="10" />
                            </p:panel>
                        </p:tab>

                        <p:tab id="topology" titleStyleClass="notClickable">
                            <f:facet name="title">
                                ...
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:panel id="wizardTopologyPnl">
                                <div class="title2">
                                    ...
                                </div>
                                <p:spacer height="10" />
                                <p:panel id="projectCreateTopologyPnl" style="border:0;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <div class="col-left title3">
                                            ...
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-right title3">
                                            ...
                                        </div>
                                    </f:facet>

                                    <h:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="grid" columnClasses="grid3,grid3,grid3_2">

                                        <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="topologyLeftPnl">

                                            <ui:include src="/auth/admin/project/includes/flexiTopologyOptions.xhtml">
                                                <ui:param name="beanPage" value="#{projectCreatePage}" />
                                                <ui:param name="idPrefix" value="projectCreateWizard" />
                                                <ui:param name="renderId" value=":projectCreateWizardFrm:topologyMiddlePnl" />
                                                <ui:param name="enableDnD" value="false" />
                                                <ui:param name="dragId" value=":projectCreateWizardFrm:topologyFlexiComponentsSelectedFieldset" />
                                                <ui:param name="dropId" value=":projectCreateWizardFrm:topologyFlexiComponentsSelectedDataList" />
                                            </ui:include>

                                        </h:panelGroup>

                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                            <p:panel id="topologyMiddlePnl" styleClass="general-content">
                                                <div class="title4">
                                                    ...
                                                </div>
                                                <br />
                                                <h:panelGroup id="topologyFlexiComponentsPnl">
                                                    ...
                                                    <p:fieldset id="topologyFlexiComponentsSelectedFieldset">
                                                        <p:dataList type="unordered" id="topologyFlexiComponentsSelectedDataList"
                                                                    value="#{projectCreatePage.revision.topology.sortedTopologyModuleDefList}" var="flexi">
                                                            <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                                                                ...
                                                                <div class="col-right">
                                                                    ...
                                                                </div>
                                                            </h:panelGroup>
                                                        </p:dataList>
                                                    </p:fieldset>

                                                </h:panelGroup>
                                            </p:panel>
                                        </h:panelGroup>

                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                            <p:panel id="topologyRightPnl" styleClass="general-content">
                                                <h:panelGroup id="topologyFlexiComponentDetailPnl">
                                                    <div class="title4">
                                                        ...
                                                    </div>
                                                    ...
                                                    <h:panelGrid id="topologyFlexiComponentDetailTbl" columns="2" columnClasses="form-label, form-value"
                                                                 rendered="#{projectCreatePage.flexiComponent != null}">

                                                        ...
                                                    </h:panelGrid>

                                                    <h:panelGroup id="flexiComponentParamsPnl">
                                                        <ui:include src="/auth/admin/project/includes/flexiTopologyParams.xhtml">
                                                            <ui:param name="beanPage" value="#{projectCreatePage}" />
                                                        </ui:include>
                                                    </h:panelGroup>

                                                    <h:panelGroup id="topologyPtvPnl">
                                                        <ui:include src="/auth/admin/project/includes/flexiTopologyPtv.xhtml">
                                                            <ui:param name="beanPage" value="#{projectCreatePage.projectPtvPage}" />
                                                            <ui:param name="visible"
                                                                      value="#{projectCreatePage.flexiComponent != null and projectCreatePage.flexiComponent.moduleDef.name == 'PTV'}" />
                                                            <ui:param name="editable"
                                                                      value="#{!projectCreatePage.disabledAfterSaved and projectCreatePage.editTopology}" />
                                                            <ui:param name="parentRenderId" value=":projectCreateWizardFrm" />
                                                        </ui:include>
                                                    </h:panelGroup>

                                                    ...
                                                </h:panelGroup>
                                            </p:panel>
                                        </h:panelGroup>

                                    </h:panelGrid>

                                    <h:panelGroup id="topologyPopupPnl">
                                        ...
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                </p:panel>
                                <p:spacer height="10" />
                            </p:panel>
                        </p:tab>

                        <p:tab id="machine" titleStyleClass="notClickable">
                            <f:facet name="title">
                                <h:panelGroup styleClass="stepNumber">
                                    ...
                                </h:panelGroup>
                                ...
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:panel id="wizardMachinePnl">
                                <div class="title2">
                                    ...
                                </div>
                                <p:spacer height="10" />
                                <p:panel id="projectCreateMachinePnl" style="border:0;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <div class="col-left title3">
                                            ...
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-right title3">
                                            ...
                                        </div>
                                    </f:facet>

                                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="grid" columnClasses="grid2,grid2_2">

                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                            <p:panel id="projectCreateMachineLeftPnl" styleClass="general-content">
                                                <div class="title4">
                                                    ...
                                                </div>
                                                <br />
                                                <h:panelGroup id="machineComponentsPnl">
                                                    <p:dataList id="machineComponentsDataList"
                                                                value="#{projectCreatePage.revision.topology.sortedTopologyModuleDefList}" var="flexi" type="unordered"
                                                                rowIndexVar="idx">
                                                        ...
                                                    </p:dataList>
                                                </h:panelGroup>
                                                <p:remoteCommand name="clickTopologyComponentDiagramElement"
                                                                 actionListener="#{projectCreatePage.onFlexiTopologyDiagramClick}"
                                                                 update="projectCreateWizardFrm:projectCreateMachineRightPnl" />
                                            </p:panel>
                                        </h:panelGroup>

                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                            <p:panel id="projectCreateMachineRightPnl" styleClass="general-content">
                                                <div class="title4">
                                                    <...
                                                </div>
                                                ...
                                                <h:panelGroup id="machineComponentDetailPnl" rendered="#{projectCreatePage.flexiComponent != null}">
                                                    <h:panelGrid id="machineComponentMachineSelectionTbl" columns="2" columnClasses="form-label, form-value">

                                                        ...

                                                        <h:panelGroup id="serverFarmLblPnl">
                                                           ...
                                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                                        <h:panelGroup id="serverFarmVallPnl">
                                                            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{projectCreatePage.revision.selectedServerFarm == null}">
                                                                ...
                                                                <div class="message-description">
                                                                    <h:outputText value="#{msg['workspace_hosting_location_desc']}" />
                                                                </div>
                                                            </h:panelGroup>
                                                            ...
                                                        </h:panelGroup>

                                                        <h:panelGroup id="flexiMachineLblPnl">
                                                           ...
                                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                                        <h:panelGroup id="flexiMachineValPnl">
                                                           ...
                                                        </h:panelGroup>

                                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                                </h:panelGroup>

                                                <h:panelGroup id="flexiComponentMachinePnl">
                                                    <ui:include src="/auth/admin/project/includes/flexiMachineDetail.xhtml">
                                                        <ui:param name="beanPage" value="#{projectCreatePage}" />
                                                    </ui:include>
                                                </h:panelGroup>

                                            </p:panel>
                                        </h:panelGroup>

                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                </p:panel>
                                <p:spacer height="10" />
                            </p:panel>
                        </p:tab>

                        <p:tab id="revision" titleStyleClass="notClickable">
                            <style>
                                .ui-button-text-icon-left .ui-button-text {
                                    padding: 0.3em 1em .3em 2.1em!important;
                                }
                            </style>
                            <f:facet name="title">
                                <h:panelGroup styleClass="stepNumber">
                                    <h:outputText value="5"/>
                                </h:panelGroup>
                                ...
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:panel id="wizardRevisionPnl">
                                <div class="title2">
                                    ...
                                </div>
                                <p:spacer height="10" />
                                <h:panelGroup id="projectCreateRevisionPnl" styleClass="project-create-revision-panel">
                                    <h:panelGrid id="projectCreateRevisionTbl" columns="2" columnClasses="form-label, form-value">

                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                            ...
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                            <p:fileUpload id="attachModel" label="#{msg['system_add']}"
                                                          listener="#{projectCreatePage.onQmodelFileUpload}"
                                                          update="uploadedQModelFileTbl" auto="true"
                                                          accept="#{projectCreatePage.getProjectHelper().getQmodelAcceptFileType()}"
                                                          disabled="#{projectCreatePage.disabledAfterSaved}"/>

                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                        ...
                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                            <p:dataGrid id="uploadedQModelFileTbl" columns="1" value="#{projectCreatePage.revision.projectRevisionFileList}"
                                                        var="item" rendered="#{projectCreatePage.revision.projectRevisionFileList != null}"
                                                        emptyMessage="#{msg['template_qpa_files_empty']}">
                                                ...
                                            </p:dataGrid>
                                        </h:panelGroup>

                                        ...
                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                            <h:inputText value="#{projectCreatePage.revision.applicationId}" size="40" maxlength="100" autocomplete="false"
                                                         disabled="#{projectCreatePage.disabledAfterSaved}" styleClass="project-create-revision-input" />
                                            <div class="message-description">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{msg['project_revision_application_id_desc']}" />
                                            </div>
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                        ...
                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                            ...
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                            ...
                                            <div class="message-description">
                                                ...
                                            </div>
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                            ...
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                            ...
                                            <div class="message-description">
                                                ...
                                            </div>
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                            ...
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="databaseStoreChkBox" value="#{projectCreatePage.datasetStoreEnabled}"
                                                                 disabled="#{projectCreatePage.disabledAfterSaved}">
                                            <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{projectCreatePage.onDatasetStoreEnabledChange}" />
                                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['project_database_enable']}" />
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="databaseChkBox" value="#{projectCreatePage.databaseEnabled}"
                                                                 disabled="true" onclick="return false;"
                                        />

                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                            ...
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                        ...
                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                </h:panelGroup>
                                <p:spacer height="10" />
                            </p:panel>
                        </p:tab>

                        <p:tab id="confirm" titleStyleClass="notClickable">
                            <f:facet name="title">
                                <h:panelGroup styleClass="stepNumber">
                                    <h:outputText value="6" />
                                </h:panelGroup>
                                ...
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:panel id="wizardConfirmPnl" style="min-height:200px;">
                                <div class="title2">
                                    ...
                                </div>
                                <p:spacer height="10" />
                                <h:panelGroup id="projectCreateConfirmPnlGrp" styleClass="col-center-wrap">
                                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="col-center-content">
                                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="col-center">

                                            <qtag:baseMessages id="nestedMsgs1" />
                                            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!projectCreatePage.validationFailed}">
                                                ...
                                            </h:panelGroup>
                                            ...

                                            <p:spacer height="10" />

                                            <h:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="col-center" rendered="#{projectCreatePage.webActionPending}">
                                                ...
                                            </h:panelGrid>

                                            <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="col-center" rendered="#{!projectCreatePage.webActionPending}">
                                                ...
                                            </h:panelGrid>

                                        </h:panelGrid>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                </h:panelGroup>
                                <p:spacer height="10" />
                            </p:panel>
                        </p:tab>

                    </p:wizard>
                </h:form>
            </sec:authorize>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </ui:define>
```

Comment: Is this your error: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=61848

it looks like you are trying to include your own jQuery version.  Don't do that. Always use PF version.

Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53001810/uncaught-typeerror-this-jq-fileupload-is-not-a-function-in-prime-faces-4-0-when

Comment: @Melloware Thanks for your answer but unfortunately, I currently not including any other jQuery version but still having this issue.